# Can Google Calendar be customized via user-provided "Labs" features?

Tags: customization, google-calendar

Google Calendar has the option of being customized by enabling features under the "Labs" setting. I would like to make my own customizations similar to these Lab features. Is this possible?

Comment: Labs features are limited to Google employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, users cannot add their own labs features to this list.

You can however suggest a labs feature, the link is provided on the Labs page: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/calendar

Not sure how often, if ever, they check this, but you cannot add a user-generated lab.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop your own "gadgets" though: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/gadgets/sidebar/?csw=1#developing - they give you limited access to specified areas.  Not full access as we'd all hope but perhaps enough for certain projects.